# Center items at start/end of FlatList React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently using a `FlatList` to render these 3 options which can be clicked: [image]

The code for centering a item is working but since the first and the last element are at the edge of the `FlatList` I also want them to be at the center when I select them. How can I modify my code so that these two can be moved to the center when scrolling in the direction of each one?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap those components in a view, give to them the same width and then adjust centering.

```
// Your render item should be like
<View style={{justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", alignContent: "center", width: 150}}>
  <Text>{text}</Text>
</View>
```

If FlatList is not mandatory to use, I'll suggest to use a simple view with three components, that maybe fits better:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around", alignItems: "center", alignContent: "center"}}>
   <Item text="yesterday" />
   <Item text="today" />
   <Item text="tomorrow" />
</View>
```

As before, you can give a fixed width or let the item grow based of the width of the parent.